# How do I create a circle-pattern effect on window-glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

I'm currently working to re-create this little scene in my windowsill in Blender with Cycles.

[image]

My window-glass is covered with a thin sheet of plastic, which has a circle-pattern on it. This gives the following lighting-effect:

[image]

**QUESTION: How do I create the circle-pattern effect on the window-glass?**

- Do I need to model an extra glass layer on top of the existing glass-pane?
- Can this be done by adding a transparent texture to the window-glass-material ?
- Can this be done through adding a extra Cycles shader to the window-glass-material?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It can be done by applying a texture to the** ***Displacement*** **input of the glass material node**. The glass must have some roughness to it.

You can use a texture like this one, made of two circles shifted by half their diameter and ridged in a concentric fashion (in your picture it looks more like an hexagonal packing, so if you're going for an exact copy you shouldn't use my mockup):

[image]

Then assign a material to the glass. I suggest using *Principled BSDF* with nearly 1.00 transmission; it must have some roughness in order to scatter light (the higher the roughness, the stronger the halo). Just plug the image texture into the *Displacement* socket of the *Material output*, but make sure to strongly decrease its effect by using a *Math > Multiply* node and setting the value to a very small number.

[image]

Finally, you should get something like this:

[image]

P.S. A realistic window wouldn't be just a plane, but rather a solid. Make sure that you *don't* apply the texture to the opposite face too.